# What is the adjective equivalent to "content"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, how does one say the equivalent to "a day which made me content" or a "contenting" day?

Comment: Then you are not actually looking for an adjectival form of "content". You are looking for an adjectival form of "make content".

Comment: ...which would normally be *satisfy*. General Reference.

Comment: I think he is looking for a synonym to *content*

Comment: Perhaps this [usage note](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/content_2) is helpful to you

Comment: @FumbleFingers: so you mean that what is looked for is an adjective? 'satisfactual'?

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is most likely contentful, which although uncommon, is a delightful word. For example "it was a contentful day at the waterfront."

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with "satisfying," "fulfilling" or "rewarding."

As in, "It was a satisfying/ fulfilling/ rewarding day."

Comment: I don't think *contending* is a synonym for *satisfying*.  What's your source?

Comment: Hello Noah. It never is. "Contending" is a perfectly different word. I'm basing my answer on his "a day WHICH MADE ME CONTENT" clue. Obviously, you can tell that the OP is confused about that particular point.

Comment: I just glanced at your answer and I noticed that you are suggesting synonyms for "content" and "satisfied." You chose to pursue his clue about here misused "contending" (content) while I chose to pursue his other clue

Comment: No prob, Noah! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of synonyms for *content* from **Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus.**

> Contented, satisfied, pleased, gratified, fulfilled, happy, cheerful, glad; unworried, untroubled, at ease, at peace, tranquil, serene.

You can't say *contending day*. *Contending* is an adjective and means *competing*.

> The debate continued between the *contending* parties.